# NextJS type errors not showing with npm run dev

Tags: typescript, next.js

If I have a typescript error, I can see it in my editor but not in the browser, nor in the terminal running `npm run dev`. It **does** show when running `npm run build`.

Is there any way to make type errors apparent during `npm run dev` in the terminal and the browser window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know currently there is no easy way to enable checking during development https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/12735#issuecomment-626869676.
It was done on purpose to speed up the development.

Maybe it would be helpful to know that you can disable those errors for the build.
Add this to your next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  typescript: {
    ignoreBuildErrors: true
  }
};
```

See [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/typescript) for the documentation of `ignoreBuildErrors`.

Comment: I think that you should not ignore build errors for production build as this masks the actual error and may lead to unnoticed bugs.